# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::sheetNameExists()

Tags: php, excel

I'm getting this error when I try and generate an excel document anyone know where this error is coming from?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   PHPExcel::sheetNameExists() in
>   /public_html/docs/PHP/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php:835 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /public_html/docs/PHP/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(337):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->setTitle('Worksheet', false) #1
>   /public_html/docs/PHP/PHPExcel.php(108):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->__construct(Object(PHPExcel)) #2
>   /public_html/docs/SendDocument.php(33):
>   PHPExcel->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in
>   /public_html/docs/PHP/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 835

```
<?php
//Excel Data
    $Spo = $_SESSION["spo"];
    $Cont = $_SESSION["contractNum"];
    $Site = $_SESSION["siteMan"];
    $Job = $_SESSION["jtd"];
    $ObBrief = $_SESSION["ob_Des"];
    $ObAgreed = $_SESSION["ob_Act"];
    $ObDate = $_SESSION["date1"];
    $GoBrief = $_SESSION["good_Des"];
    $GoAgreed = $_SESSION["good_Act"];
    $GoDate = $_SESSION["date2"];
    $FeBrief = $_SESSION["fe_Des"];
    $FeAgreed = $_SESSION["fe_Act"];
    $FeDate = $_SESSION["date3"];
    $Q1 = '';
    $Q2 = '';
    $Q3 = '';
    $Q4 = '';
    $Q5 = '';
    $Q6 = '';
    $Q7 = '';
    $Q8 = '';
    $Q9 = '';
    $Q10 = '';
    $Add = $_SESSION["addCom"];
    $Name = $_SESSION["name"];
    $Title = $_SESSION["title"];
    $Date = $_SESSION["date4"]; 

    Include_once 'PHP/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Senior Managers Site Tour');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);

    $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                )
            )
        );  

//Set Up
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E1','Senior Managers Site Tour');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:N70')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A70');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('N1:N70');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:M68')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);

    $titleArray = array(
        'font'  => array(
            'bold'  => true,
            'size'  => 32,
        ));

    $styleTitleAlign = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        )
    );

//Title
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:D4');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E1:M4');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B5:M5');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray($titleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray($styleTitleAlign);

//Basic Information
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B6:D6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E6:G6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H6:J6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('K6:M6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B7:D7');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E7:M7');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B8:D8');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E8:M8');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B9:M10');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B6','Site / Project / Object:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E6', $Spo);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H6','Contract Number:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('K6',$Cont);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B7','Site Manager:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E7',$Site);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B8','Job / Task Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E8',$Job);

//Observation
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B11:M11');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B12:E12');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F12:I12');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J12:M12');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B13:E17');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F13:I17');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J13:M17');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B18:M19');  

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B11','OBSERVATION (areas where improvement can be made).');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B12','Brief Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B13',$ObBrief);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F12','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F13',$ObAgreed);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J12','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J13',$ObDate);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B11')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

//Good Practices
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B20:M20');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B21:E21');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F21:I21');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J21:M21');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B22:E26');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F22:I26');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J22:M26');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B27:M28');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B20','GOOD PRACTICES (Commendable acts and actions, Improvements, Innovations etc).');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B21','Brief Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B22',$GoBrief);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F21','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F22',$GoAgreed);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J21','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J22',$GoDate);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B20')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

//Feedback Given & Received
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B29:M29');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B30:E30');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F30:I30');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J30:M30');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B31:E35');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F31:I35');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J31:M35');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B36:M37');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B29','FEEDBACK GIVEN & RECEIVED');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B30','Brief Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B31',$FeBrief);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F30','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('F31',$FeAgreed);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J30','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J31',$FeDate);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B29')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

//General Impression
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B38:M38');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B39:G39');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H39:M39');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B40:G40');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H40:M40');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B41:M41');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B42:K42');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L42:M42');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B43:K43');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L43:M43');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B44:K44');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L44:M44');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B45:K45');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L45:M45');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B46:K46');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L46:M46');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B47:M47');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B48:K48');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L48:M48');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B49:K49');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L49:M49');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B50:K50');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L50:M50');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B51:K51');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L51:M51');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B52:K52');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L52:M52');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B53:M54');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B38','GENERAL IMPRESSION');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B39','1 = No evidence / poor / no understanding');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H39','2 = Some evidence / understanding / not consistent');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B40','3 = Requirements in place / basic unerstanding');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H40','4 = Detailed understanding / more than minimum standards');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B38')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B41','CULTURE');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B42','Is the CDP obvious - You Said / We Did Boards; Feedback Stations; Posters?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L42',$Q1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B43','Are there any Speak Up Coaches on this site?');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L43',$Q2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B44','Are Focus Leader meetings happening?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L44',$Q3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B45','Mention the Mental Tools, do people understand them?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L45',$Q4);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B46','Ask what "Never Harm" means to the teams:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L46',$Q5);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B41')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B47','SYSTEM');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B48','Are first impressions good, site signage, induction etc?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L48',$Q6);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B49','Is the site tidy, well laid out etc?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L49',$Q7);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B50','Are morning briefings / daily risk assessment carried out?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L50',$Q8);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B51','Have all the team been briefed & signed onto the RAMS?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L51',$Q9);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B52','Ask what they would do if there was a change in the work activity i.e. not in RAMS?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('L52',$Q10);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B47')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

//Comments
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B55:M55');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B56:M63');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B64:M65');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B55','Additional Comments:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B56',$Add);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B55')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

//Completed By
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B66:M66');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B67:C67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('D67:G67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H67:I67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J67:M67');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B68:C68');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('D68:G68');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H68:M68');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B69:M70');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B66','COMPLETED BY');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B67','Name:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('D67',$Name);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('H67','Title:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('J67',$Title);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B68','Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('D68',$Date);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B66')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('D6D6D6');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
    $objWriter->save('Senior Managers Site Tour.xls');
?>
```

Comment: It's not in the code you pasted, the errors refer to the classes used to do the work, I guess - and something is amiss. Exactly what, I dunno, since I've never used to PHPExcel-system. But the error-message is pretty clear: the method you're trying to call doesn't exist. Might be a typo (it's called something else), or you haven't loaded the classes needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Seems that are using wrong `PHPExcel` version and you need to re-install the library

See [this answer] for more details.

### Investigation

After a code follow-through via [PHPExcel repository on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) the following observations can be made:

When [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php) is instantiated, it's constructor builds worksheets array with one [Worksheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php).

```
// Initialise worksheet collection and add one worksheet
$this->workSheetCollection = array();
$this->workSheetCollection[] = new PHPExcel_Worksheet($this);
```

Notice that `Worksheet`, when instantiated, gets the `PHPExcel` instance into its constructor. And this object is assigned to the `Worksheet`s property `parent`:

```
public function __construct(PHPExcel $pParent = null, $pTitle = 'Worksheet')
{
    // Set parent and title
    $this->parent = $pParent;
    ...
```

Now, we see that the `setTitle` method is called from the `Worksheet`:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Senior Managers Site Tour');
```

Inside `setTitle` there's the following code:

```
if ($this->parent) {
    // Is there already such sheet name?
    if ($this->parent->sheetNameExists($pValue)) {
        ...
```

And here the exception is thrown.

We can clearly see the method present in `PHPExcel` code and we can see that the parent is correctly recognized as a member of this class. So the only conclusion is that **wrong version of `PHPExcel.php` is used**. The missing function has only been added in v. `1.8`.